# NextJS router encode query character

Tags: javascript, react-router, next.js

I'm having an issue when i try to open a new page with NextJS router.

I passed my parameter like:

```html
router.push({
  pathname: '/',
  query: { id: '12344567' },
 })
```

sometimes (like rarely) it will redirect my page to something like

```
/%3Fid=12344567
```

It's weird because it's rarely happened and when it does i don't know how to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

its the parsed shape of the url (after translating special characters). %3F is an escape code for ?, which is required when passing a query param.

Example of passing param:
`BASE_URL/${PARAM}`

Example of query passing: `BASE_URL/?${QUERY_NAME}=${QUERY_VALUE}`